# How to get mouse movement and left/right click in dos

Tags: c, mouse, interrupt, dos, dosbox

after some reading, I understand that 116 handler should be used for the mouse, after using it, only left/right click of the mouse works, but when I move the mouse, the interrupt does not happen. how can I get mouse's movement?
Here's what I've done so far:
(By the way, should I call the original 116 ISR, or it is optional?)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>

//Will count in milliseconds the time
volatile int timeCounter = 0;
volatile int isPressed = 0;
void exitMode();
void interrupt (*Int116Save)(void);/* Pointer to org ISR116*/
void interrupt (*Int8Save) (void); /* Pointer to org ISR8*/

void interrupt INT8_Handler(void) {
/*We always have to call the original ISR8 before editing the clock*/
/* Call original ISR8 */
    asm{
    PUSHF
    CALL DWORD PTR Int8Save;
    } 
timeCounter++;
//timeCounter = 20 is 1 second, so 1200 is 1 minute, 2400 is 2 minutes
if(timeCounter > 2400){
    printf("User is dreaming, exiting...");
    exitMode();
}
} /* END INT8 Handler */

void interrupt mouseMoved(void){
    /*We always have to call the original ISR116 before listening for a mouse input*/
    /* Call original ISR116 */
     asm{
        PUSHF
        CALL DWORD PTR Int116Save
        }
        isPressed++;
        printf("\nMouse moved\clicked...\n");
}

/*If user is dreaming for 2 minutes, we come here through the clock's handler and exit*/
void exitMode()
{
        printf("\nC: Terminating...\n");
        setvect(8, Int8Save ); /*return org ISR8*/
        setvect(116, Int116Save);/*return org ISR116*/
        exit(0);
}

void main(){
    printf("Please move/click the mouse. \n");

    //Mouse
    Int116Save=getvect(116);
    setvect(116, mouseMoved);


    //Clock
    Int8Save=getvect(8);
    setvect(8, INT8_Handler);

    //
    while(isPressed<100);

    //End the program and return the vect's as needed.
        printf("\nC: Terminating...\n");
        setvect(8, Int8Save ); /*return org ISR8*/
        setvect(116, Int116Save); /*return org ISR116*/

}
```

Comment: What is the "116 handler"? I'm not familiar with the C library that you're using. Is this equivalent to `int 116h` in assembly? Normally, the DOS mouse interrupt is `int 33h`, but that does depend on the driver you have installed.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes. and about the int 33h, I will check that out and update asap.

Comment: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_33.html (I can't find *any* hits online for interrupt 116h. Are you sure you don't mean 16h?)

Comment: Okay thanks, I believe they meant just for clicking the mouse. Moving the mouse are too many interrupts. Thanks Cody! @CodyGray

Comment: Note that you don't hook interrupt 33h. It's not a hardware interrupt like the timer interrupt (INT 8) that you're hooking. INT 33h is an API, you invoke it with various parameters to perform various mouse related operations. One of those operations is to install a callback handler, INT 33h, AX=0Ch.

Comment: @CodyGray Solved. it was just for mouse clicks.

Comment: @RossRidge Solved. it was just for mouse clicks. Thanks